# Select every ranges at once Vba

Tags: vba, excel

How can I code loop to or made to select all possiblities at once. "In" should be first in selected range and extend down to the first Late and copy similar ranges down the list.
Thanks for the feedback

```
SelectBetween()
    Dim findrow As Long, findrow2 As Long
    On Error GoTo Err
    findrow = Range("A:A").Find("In", Range("A1")).Row
    findrow2 = Range("A:A").Find("Late", Range("A" & findrow)).row
    Range("A" & findrow & ":A" & findrow2).copy
    Exit Sub
Err:
MsgBox "Cells unspecified"
End Sub
```

Comment: Any attempt to answer this question would require some guesswork. **Please edit your question to make it clearer**

Comment: So if cell A2 and A10 both contain "In", and cell A8 and A16 both contain "Late", you want to select A2:A8,A2:A16,A8:A10,A10:A16 (i.e. A2:A16)?

Answer (score 1):

Nice try so far. A little suggestion: Find method returns a range object, use it can grant you some advantages.

```
Private Sub SelectBetween()
    Dim firstInCell, tmpInCell, firstLateCell, tmpLateCell, copyRange As Range
    On Error GoTo Err
    Set firstInCell = Range("A:A").Find("In", Range("A1"))
    Set firstLateCell = Range("A:A").Find("Late", Range("A1"))

    Set tmpInCell = firstInCell
    Set tmpLateCell = firstLateCell
    Set copyRange = Range(tmpInCell, tmpLateCell)

    Do
        Set tmpInCell = Range("A:A").Find("In", tmpInCell)
        Set tmpLateCell = Range("A:A").Find("Late", tmpInCell)
        Set copyRange = Union(copyRange, Range(tmpInCell, tmpLateCell))
    Loop While tmpInCell.Address <> firstInCell.Address

    copyRange.Copy
    Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox "Cells unspecified"
End Sub
```

Logic: Find the first target and store them into `firstInCell` and `firstLateCell`. And I built a `copyRange` to save all matched ranges. The `Find` function has a feature that it will scroll back to the beginning if nothing has been found, therefore I can check the result to determine the loop is finished or not.

Comment: Thankyou for the detail answer. Now on the other end how would I implement a delete to delete the rows without storing any of the data? Thanks for all the help

Comment: If you have the Row number, you can delete it by `Rows(i).Delete`. The best  way for deleting several rows is `Union` them first, and delete them at once. Otherwise it will take lots of time for deleting one by one.

Comment: I see well thank you again, your help is appreciated.